# Access a class's method within the class

Tags: python

Let's say i have this class called grid for 2D arrays:

```
class grid:

  def __init__(self, N, S, F, p):

    ## Make sure start and end are within the grid
    assert N > 2
    assert S[0] < N
    assert S[1] < N
    assert F[0] < N
    assert F[1] < N

    assert S[0] > 0
    assert S[1] > 0
    assert F[0] > 0
    assert F[1] > 0

    self.N = N

    self.grid = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.int32)

    ## Surround the grid with obstacles

    self.grid[0, :] = 1
    self.grid[N - 1, :] = 1
    self.grid[:, 0] = 1
    self.grid[:, N - 1] = 1



    obstacle_free_points = {S, F}


  ### Fill the grid with obstacles. 
  ### An obstacle at position (x,y) -> grid[x,y]=1
  ### Ensure there is a path from S to F
  ### Your code here ###


  def isReachable(self): 
    visited= np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.int32)
    queue=[]
    queue.append(S) 
    visited[S] = True






  def adjacent(self, S):
    adjacent_nodes = []
    for n in (node[0] - 1, node[1]), (node[0] + 1, node[1]), (node[0], node[1] - 1), (node[0], node[1] + 1):
      if self.grid[n] == 0:
        adjacent_nodes.append(n)

    return adjacent_node
```

What i would like to do is use adjacent inside isReachable.More specificaly given a pair of numbers (x,y) find all the adjacent array cells using method adjacent.Adjacent works just fine if i use it outside of the class but calling it from another method produces errors.How could this be done?

Comment: what errors does it produce?

Comment: Use `self`. Notice when you create normal methods inside a class, you always have to pass at least one argument. By convention, `self` is used as this argument name. `self` represents the current instance, so if you need to use a method of that instance, you would act just as you would if you were outside the class -- by using the class instance, dot, and then the method name. So `self.adjacent(...)` in this case as the answer below states.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `self` keyword.

```
self.adjacent(...)
```